# Why does my custom block disappear after page reload?

Tags: blocks, 9

I have created a custom block with a custom module (Example: https://www.webwash.net/programmatically-create-block-drupal-8/). The goal is to display some external content, which is working. The only issue is if i reload the frontend page where this block is loaded, it disappears. I have to flush caches to bring it back.

Does anybody know the reason why have to flush caches to bring the block back? How can I make the block persistent?

Function for loading the external url:

```php
class LebenslagenGeburt extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    return [
      '#markup' => $this->_populate_markup(),
    ];
  }

  private function _populate_markup() {
    
    function getter($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }

    echo getter('https://www.muster.at/.syndication?pageShortcut=L-GB&format=html');
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `echo` with `return`

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. Now i know the difference between echo and return.